# Javascript click event is not trigging on a tag

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="button" type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('hello')">
<a href='http://google.com' onclick="javascript:alert('hello')">Google</a>
```

want to trig click event.**In url Address bar**

```
javascript:document.getElementById("button").click(); //working find  
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click(); //not working, Why
```

This is basically automatic click button to accept/reject all request in facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support clicking on an anchor (`<a>` tag). But, there is a workaround: with some custom JavaScript code, you can simulate the click on an anchor.

This is a short snippet I created. It simulates the actions you'd expect, even is you use the target attribute. I built in a check to see if the method actually runs on an anchor, so you could even use this method on your buttons and expect the normal behavior. You just have to add it somewhere on your page. I tested it in Safari 5.

```
Element.prototype.anchorClick = function() {
    if (this.click) return this.click();
    if (this.onclick) { var result = this.onclick(); if (!result) return result; }

    switch (this.target) {
        case '_blank': window.open(this.href); break;
        case '_parent': parent.location = this.href; break;
        case '_top': top.location = this.href; break;
        case '_self': case '': window.location = this.href; break;
        default: if (parent[this.target]) parent[this.target].location = this.href; else window.open(this.href); break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You use the snippet this way:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('anchor').anchorClick();
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].anchorClick();
```

Here the full version with some comments inside:

```
Element.prototype.anchorClick = function() {
    // If there's a click method, the element isn't an anchor
    if (this.click) {
        // Just run the click method instead
        return this.click();
    }

    // Is there an onclick method?
    if (this.onclick) {
        // Run the method and get the result
        var result = this.onclick();

        // Isn't the result true?
        if (!result) {
            // Cancel the operation and return the result
            return result;
        }
    }

    // Check the target property
    switch (this.target) {
        // _blank means a new window
        case '_blank':
            // Open the window
            window.open(this.href);
            break;

        // _parent means the parent frame
        case '_parent':
            parent.location = this.href;
            break;

        // _top means the top frame
        case '_top':
            top.location = this.href;
            break;

        // _self means the current frame
        // When there's no value for the target property, this is the expected result
        case '_self':
        case '':
            window.location = this.href;
            break;

        // The last option is a user specified frame
        default:
            // Does the frame actually exist?
            if (parent[this.target]) {
                // Yep, and we'll open the page in that frame
                parent[this.target].location = this.href;
            } else {
                // Nope, the frame doesn't exist
                // The expected behaviour (in Safari) is opening a new window
                window.open(this.href);
            }

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` worked for me in Chrome and Firefox3.6:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick();
```